# can not save files into my device android10 flutter

Tags: flutter, storage

///i can save excel file in my device witch is android10 `enter code here`this is my code

```
class excelp extends  StatefulWidget{
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
 return excelstate(); }


}class excelstate extends State<excelp>{
  @override
   openexcel(){
    var excel = Excel.createExcel();
    Sheet sheetObject = excel['SheetName'];
    sheetObject.cell(CellIndex.indexByString("A1")).value='my name is doodle';
    print('${sheetObject.cell(CellIndex.indexByString("A1")).value}');
    excel.encode().then((onValue) {
      File(join("/storage/emulated/0/Download/excel.xlsx"))
        ..createSync(recursive: true)
        ..writeAsBytesSync(onValue);
    });

  }
  int t=1;
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
     body: Center(
       child:Column(
         children: [
           Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 200),
             height:90,
             width: 120,
             child: RaisedButton(
               child: Text('press',style:TextStyle(
                 fontSize: 20,
                 fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
               )),
               onPressed:(){
                 setState(() {
                   t+=1;
                   openexcel();
                 });

               } ,
             ),
           ),
           Container(
               child:Text('$t',style:TextStyle(
                 fontSize: 20,
                 fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
               )))
         ],
       ),
     ),
   )
 ; }

}
void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home:excelp(),
  ));
}
```

and the error is
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot create file, path = '/storage/emulated/0/Download/excel.xlsx' (OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13)
i uses the permission in the manifest file but still didin't work on my device

Comment: What permission you added for Android? And have you requested user's permission in runtime?

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION"/> no i dont but how can i do that

Comment: you can check on the permission_handler on pub.dev, you can follow the example to request user's permission on storage